# How to order a list with a method in a collection class

Tags: c#

I am having some problem with a searching method.
I want to make a function inside my collection class that can find all products (objects) in my list with a specific name and there after sort the list by the price.

But because it is generic I can't "reach" the fields in the objects in my list.
Can somebody please help me?

Here is what I have tried:

```
public class ProductList<T> : ICollection<T>, IComparer<T>
{
    public List<T> _productList = new List<T>();

    // Some other methods


    // 1. try:
    public void FuncSearch_Name(string search_name, ProductList<Product> ListIn, out ProductList<Product> ListOut)
    {
        ListOut = ListIn.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(search_name)).ToList(); // Here it is complaining about that it cant not implicity convert a generic list to productlist (I dont really understand that)
    }


    // I have also tried like this:
    public void FuncSearch_name(string search_name, ref List<T> ListIn, out List<T> ListOut)
    {
        ListOut = ListIn.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(search_name)).ToList();
        ListOut.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price).ToList(); // Here it can't find Name and Price because "T" not contains them..
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time. I hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Comment: Can you restrict your `T` to a base type or interface that has what you need?

Comment: I'm confused, why are your methods inside `ProductList<T>`, when you're working with a completely different list?

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you are implementing `IComparer<T>`. Is this the comparer you're using to sort your `T` objects? If it is, you could use it for a `List.Sort`, which is *in-place* unlike `OrderByDescending`:

```
public void FuncSearch_name(string search_name, ref List<T> ListIn, out List<T> ListOut)
{
    ListOut = ListIn.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(search_name)).ToList();
    ListOut.Sort(this);
}
```

This `Sort` sorts `ListOut` directly, whereas `OrderByDescending` returns a new `IOrderedEnumerable` and *does not change* `ListOut` itself.

However, I think there might be a much simpler approach:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> FindByName(string name)
{
    myProducts.Where(p => p.Name == name).OrderByDescending(p => p.Price);
}
```

You can use this without implementing your very own collection class and `IComparer<T>`.

Comment: When I am trying the first you suggest I still have the problem that it cant find "Name"?

Answer (score 0):

Since your class is generic, and the generic parameter is not restricted, `T` could be *anything*, so there's no way for the compiler to know that your objects have a `Name` property.

It looks like your declaration should either be:

```
public class ProductList<T> : ICollection<T>, IComparer<T> where T: Product
{
    public List<T> _productList = new List<T>();
```

if Product has sub-classes, or just

```
public class ProductList : ICollection<Product>, IComparer<Product> 
{
    public List<Product> _productList = new List<Product>();
```

Also it's *unusual* for a collection of a type to implement `IComparer`. Typically that is done in a separate class.

Looking closer at your problem, `ToList<Product>` returns a `List<Product>`.  There's no way to cast a `List<Product>` to your custom class.  Since you didn't post a constructor,   The only way I can see that you can create a new `ProductList` is to add items one-by-one.  Typically a colelction type has a constructor that takes in a collection (usually a simple `IEnumerable`) to initialize it.

Either way, your collection type appears to be doing to much, and the method you're trying to implement doesn;'t interact with the class members at all.

Comment: When I do what the second you suggest, I get this error for _productlist:

"Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Eksamensprojekt.Product>' is less accessible than field 'Eksamensprojekt.ProductList._productList'"

Comment: I just found out that Product was abstract.. I have made it public. But now I have som other problems.... (Just not my day.. :( )

I have the search method:
'        public void FuncSearch_name(string search_name, ref List<Product> ListIn, out List<Product> ListOut)
        {
            ListOut = ListIn.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(search_name)).ToList();
            ListOut.Sort(this);
        }'

But when I try to call the method from main i get som error.. I write:
        'mylist.FuncSearch_name(namename, ref mylist, out nynylist);'

I says that this is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make ProductList limit `T` to an interface (or the concrete product)?

```
public class ProductList : ICollection<IProduct>, IComparer<IProduct>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could add additional constraint for the `T`:

```
interface IHasName
{
   string Name{get;}
}
```

therefore, compiler would know, how to get a name from T. However, you can do this only for your classes. For classes that are not under your control, you can just write a wrapper, that implements this interface.